# How to run an ionic app inside another ionic app

Tags: ionic4, angular8

We have a multiproject ionic app, and we need to pass from one application to another when the user clicks a button.

We can't use inAppBrowser, because both apps need to be inside of one apk.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a link that maybe can help you:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-opening-external-app/77932

First install the plugins:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-appavailability
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

Then import it like this:

```
import { InAppBrowser, AppAvailability, Device } from 'ionic-native';
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
launchExternalApp(iosSchemaName: string, androidPackageName: string, appUrl: string, httpUrl: string, username: string) {
    let app: string;
    if (Device.device.platform === 'iOS') {
        app = iosSchemaName;
    } else if (Device.device.platform === 'Android') {
        app = androidPackageName;
    } else {
        let browser = new InAppBrowser(httpUrl + username, '_system');
        return;
    }

    AppAvailability.check(app).then(
        () => { // success callback
            let browser = new InAppBrowser(appUrl + username, '_system');
        },
        () => { // error callback
            let browser = new InAppBrowser(httpUrl + username, '_system');
        }
    );
}

openInstagram(username: string) {
    this.launchExternalApp('instagram://', 'com.instagram.android', 'instagram://user?username=', 'https://www.instagram.com/', username);
}

openTwitter(username: string) {
    this.launchExternalApp('twitter://', 'com.twitter.android', 'twitter://user?screen_name=', 'https://twitter.com/', username);
}

openFacebook(username: string) {
    this.launchExternalApp('fb://', 'com.facebook.katana', 'fb://profile/', 'https://www.facebook.com/', username);
}
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But no,  because both apps need to be inside of one apk.